# Fast linear list that excludes duplicates

Tags: delphi, list, optimization, language-agnostic, conways-game-of-life

I have the following code:

```
procedure TCellBlock.GeneratePtoQ;
var
  x,y: integer;
  i: integer;
  Change: cardinal;
begin
  i:= 0;
  //Walk the grid of changed (alive) cells 
  for x:= GridMaxX downto 1 do begin
    for y:= GridMaxY downto 1 do begin
      if Active[cIndexP][x, y] then begin
        Active[cIndexP][x,y]:= false;

        //Put active items on the stack.
        ToDo[i]:= x shl 16 or y;
        Inc(i);
      end; {if}
    end; {for y}
  end; {for x}
  while i > 0 do begin
    Dec(i);
    y:= ToDo[i] and $FFFF;
    x:= ToDo[i] shr 16;

    //Calculate the cell, Change = (oldval XOR newval)
    Change:= Grid[x,y].GeneratePtoQ;

    //Mark the cells in the grid that need to be recalculated next generation.
    Active[cIndexQ][x,y]:= Active[cIndexQ][x,y] or (Change <> 0);
    Active[cIndexQ][x+1,y+1]:= Active[cIndexQ][x+1,y+1] or ((Change and $cc000000) <> 0);
    Active[cIndexQ][x+1,y]:= Active[cIndexQ][x+1,y] or ((Change and $ff000000) <> 0);
    Active[cIndexQ][x,y+1]:= Active[cIndexQ][x,y+1] or ((Change and $cccccccc) <> 0);
  end; {while}
end;
```

The above is a code snippet of a test program that calculates conway's [game of life](http://www.ibiblio.org/lifepatterns/).
The code needs to be as fast as possible. And for this purpose I'm trying different approaches.

It walks though a grid of active cells, looks to see which cells are active and puts those 
on a stack.
Next it processes the items on the stack and sees which cells have changed.
If a cell has changed it updates the changes into the grid for the next generation.

I store cells in 32bit cardinals (4 bits Y, 8 bits X) and the P (even) generations are offset 1,1 pixel relative to the Q (odd) generations, this way I only have to take 3 neighbors into account instead of 8.

**Question**
I want to get rid of the grid, I just want to deal with the stack.
**How do I implement a stack that eliminates duplicates?**

Note that it needs to be **as fast as possible** and I'm not above using dirty tricks to get that.

Comment: Well, I doubt using a stack that eliminates duplicate would make your algorithm any faster. The process itself of eliminating the duplicate would be expensive. And I don't see how using a 1,1 offset remove the needs to take all neighbors into account.

Comment: @Ken gladly I'm not the only one at both questions.

Comment: @Ken, please see the answer I've added below. I've exploited the fact that I walk though the grid in sequential order, which makes the changed cells come out in almost sequence as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of performance are you getting at the moment? I may be missing something (due to seeing only a "code snippet" without full context); but looking at your code, it currently seems highly inefficient to me. In particular `Change:= Grid[x,y].GeneratePtoQ` looks like a recursive call? Also, I don't think it's a good idea to get rid of the grid. While I get the idea of trying to build succesive generations from a much smaller change list, the grid's greatest advantage is simplicity and O(1) lookup to all neighbours.

Comment: @Craig, I run the r-pentonimo 1000 generations restarted a 100 times in 2 seconds. There's no recursion, it's just that the cells generatePtoQ happens to have the same name as grid's PtoQ. I want to get rid of the lookup grid because it forces me to loop though empty cells and I don't want to lookup any neighbors, the neighbors are in a 2D array (8 horz x 16 vert) of cells in a grid. So each cells knows where its neighbor is, no need for indirection.

Comment: @Craig, anyway I think I have the solution, look at my answer below.

Comment: @Craig just implemented the code, timing for 1000 generations of r-pentonimo (lowest count of a 100 identical runs) takes 5,9 million cycles in the improved code. It took 45 million cycles in the code in the question, a 7.6x speedup, not bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been thinking about it and I think I have a solution.

**some background**

Here's how the data is in laid out in memory

```
00 A  08  B  10   18     The bits of Individual int32's are layout like this:
01 |  09  |  11   19     00 04 08 0C 10 14 18 1C    // N-Mask: $33333333
02 |  0A  |  12   1A     01 05 09 0D 11 15 19 1D    // S-Mask: $cccccccc
03 |  0B  |  13   1B     02 06 0A 0E 12 16 1A 1E    // W-Mask: $000000ff
04 |  0C  |  14   1C     03 07 0B 0F 13 17 1B 1F    // E-Mask: $ff000000
05 |  0D  |  15   1D                                //SE-Mask: $cc000000
06 |  0E  |  16   1E                                //NW-Mask: $00000033
07 V  0F  V  17   1F     I can mask of different portions if need be.

-- Figure A: Grid --     -- Figure B: cell --       -- Table C: masks --
```

I haven't decided on the size of the building block, but this is the general idea.

Even generations are called `P`, odd generations are called `Q`.

They are staggered like this

```
 +----------------+<<<<<<<< P         00 04  08  0C  //I use a 64K lookup
 |+---------------|+                  01 05* 09* 0D  //table to lookup
 ||               ||                  02 06* 0A* 0E  //the inner* 2x2 bits from
 ||               ||                  03 07  0B  0F  //a 4x4 grid.
 +----------------+|                  //I need to do 8 lookups for a 32 bit cell
  +----------------+<<<<<<<< Q

 - Figure D: Cells are staggered -   -- Figure E: lookup --
```

This way when generating `P -> Q`, I only need to look at P itself and its S, SE, E neighbors, instead of all 8 neighbors, ditto for Q -> P. I need only look at Q itself and its N, NW and W neighbors.
Also notice that the staggering saves me time in translating the result of the lookup, because I have to do less bit shifting to put the results in place.

When I loop though a grid *(Figure A)* I walk though the cells *(Figure B)* in the order shown in figure A. Always in strictly increasing order in a P-cycle and always in decreasing order in a Q-cycle.
In fact the Q cycle works in exactly the opposite order from the P-cycle, this speeds things up by reusing the cache as much as possible.

I want to minimize using pointers as much as possible, because pointers cannot be predicted and are not accessed sequentially *(they jump all over the place)* So I want to use arrays, stacks and queues as much as possible.

**What data do to need to keep track of**
I need to keep track of only the cells that change. If a cell (that is an int32) does not change from one generation to the next I remove it from consideration.
This is what the code in the question does. It uses a grid to keep track of the changes, but I want to use a **stack**, not a grid; and I **only** want to deal with active cells I don't want to know about stable or dead cells.

**Some background on the data**
Notice how the cell itself is always monotonically increasing. As is its S-neighbor, as well as the E and SE-neighbor. I can use this info to cheat.

**The solution**
I use a stack to keep track of the cell itself and its S neighbor and a queue to keep track of its E and SE neighbor and when I'm done I merge the two.

Suppose in the Grid the following cells come out as active after I've calculated them:

```
00, 01, 08 and 15
I make the following two stacks:

stack A    stack B
00         08      a)  -A: Cell 00 itself in stack A and its E-neighbor in B
01         09      a)      Cell 00's S neighbor in stack A and its SE-n'bor in B
02         0A      b)  -B: Cell 01 is already in the stack, we only add S/SE
08         10      c)  -C: Cell 08 goes into the stack as normal
09         11      c)      We'll sort out the merge later.
15         1D      d)  -D: Cell 15 and neighbors go on as usual.
16         1E      d)

Now I push members from stack A and B onto a new stack C so that stack C has
no duplicates and it strictly increasing:

Here's the pseudo code to process the two queues:  

a:= 0; b:= 0; c:=0;
while not done do begin
  if stack[a] <= stack[b] then begin
    stack[c]:= stack[a]; inc(a); inc(c);
    if stack[a] = stack[b] then inc(b);
  end
  else begin
    stack[c]:= stack[b]; inc(b); inc(c);
  end;
end; {while}
```

**And even better**
I don't have to actually do the two stacks and the merging as two separate steps, if I make `A` a stack and `B` a queue, I can do the second step described in the pseudo code and the building of the two stacks in one pass.

**Note**
As a cell changes its S, E or SE border does not necessary need to change, but I can test for that using the masks in table C, and only add the cells that really need checking in the next generation to the list.

**Benefits**

1. Using this scheme, I only ever have to walk through **one** stack with active cells when calculating cells, so I don't waste time looking at dead or inactive cells.
2. I only do sequential memory accesses, maximizing cache usage.
3. Building the stack with new changes for the next generations only requires one extra temporary queue, which I process in strictly sequential order.
4. I do no sorting and the minimum of comparisons.
5. I don't have to keep track of the neighbors of each individual cells (int32), I only need to keep track of the neighbors *(S,E,SE, N,W,NW)* of the grids, this keeps the memory overhead to a minimum.
6. I don't need to keep track of a cells status, I only need to count dead cells (A cell is either dead, because it was dead before, or because it **changed** into dead. All the active cells are in my TODO stack, this saves bookkeeping time and memory space.
7. The algorithm runs in o(n) time where (n) is the number of **active** cells, it excludes dead cells, stable cells and cells that oscillate with period 2.
8. I only ever deal with 32 bit cardinals, which is the much faster than using int16's.

Comment: I must admit I'm still not sure how your algorythm is actually working... and I'm curious about what kind of speed this design can get.  How fast you generate a generation for, lets say, a 500x500 grid? (considering you'll get faster over time because of #1, how much time for gen 1, 500, 1000?)

Comment: @ken posted the sourcecode of a working version as a 2nd answer. I hope I did not obscure the intend too much and it's understandable a lot of the comments got lost because the design has been in flux

Answer (score 1):

if i understood what you asked you want the stack to have no duplication values. i'm not a delphi person but if it was java i would created a hashmap/ map tree and add each value to the map and before adding it to the stack check if it's already in the hash. you can also add all the values th the hash iterate it but you will loose the order of the hash.

Comment: Algorithms are (largely) language-agnostic!

Comment: that's what I'm doing now with the grid, but I want to get rid of the grid and only deal with a list/stack like structure. using a hash is not a bad idea though.

Comment: You say that you only want a stack, but what you describe is NOT a stack. A stack does not check for duplicates. This whould change the performance characteristics tremendously from O(1) to O(n). IMHO a stack in combination with a hash set or hash map is the right solution.

Comment: @Smasher, The activeGrid in the question is basically a hash, I decided to not use a hash and use a stack + queue instead, You had me thinking about some sort of hashing option for a while though.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd take a completely different approach. First I don't see how you don't have to take all neighbours into account just because of using a 1,1 offset and then I doubt that bitshifting tricks make the algorithm much faster (often enough it's the contrary, but then it could be mem bandwidth constrained in which case we'd win a bit)

So I'd just go for the one thing that should bring by far the largest performance gain: Making the algorithm multithreaded. In our world of Quad/Hex/Octacores worrying about a few percent performance increases while wasting 300% or more seems silly. So if we'd ignore the active grids and check all fields the algorithm would be trivial with some great scaling, especially since one could easily vectorize the algorithm, but then that's not especially work efficient so I'd try some different approaches towards multithreading an algorithm that only takes the active cells in account.

First instead of getting rid of the grid I'd double it: One src and one dest grid - that are swapped each round. No locking to access the grid necessary, don't have to worry about when updating the fields and no stale entries (important for multithreading we want to use the cache after all).

Now the simplest solution would be to use some kind of concurrent list structure (no idea about delphi libraries) for the active cells and let each thread steal from it and add new active cells to another. With a good lock-free implementation of a concurrent queue (basically whatever the replacement of [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is in delphi) or something similar could be quite nice and simple. For a better performance instead of adding single nodes to the list, I'd think about adding whole chunks to the list, say in sizes of 10 or so - more work with less overhead but if we make the chunks too large we lose parallelism.

I can think of other solutions like giving every thread one list of active cells to work through (or more exactly one list for all and different offsets) but then we have to between each run gather all new entries (not much synchronization overhead but some copying) into a list - worth a try I assume.

Comment: A: Threading looks like a cool idea, but slows things way way way way way wayyyy down on small patterns, because of the enormous overhead involved. In big patterns I'm looking into it, but that is the **last** step. B: The grid is already doubled. C: The code is meant as a starting point for implementation in CUDA, where you run thousands of threads in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is speed (and only speed).  There is a few tricks that can speed things up a LOT. My own implementation of the Conway's Game of Life use those tricks to make it faster.  Note that it is VERY expensive on memory.

1. Each cells are an object
2. Each cell object contains its X/Y coordinates
3. Each cell object contains a "live" counters of the number of Alive neighbors. (When a cell turns On/Off, it notify it's neighbor so they update their counters.
4. To make #3 works, when the next generation is calculated, cells are not turned On/Off right away.  They are instead stacked into a list until all cells are calculated.
5. Each cell has a counter which indicate which is the last generation they changed on. That avoid calculating the same cell twice. (My alternative to the stack that eliminates duplicates)
6. The list of #5 is reused on the next generation, as only the neighbors of a cell that changed on the previous generation can change on the current one.

There are some of the tricks I use to speed up the generation. Some of the tricks listed here will get you a lot more than multithreading your implementation.  But using both those and multithread will get the most performance possible.

As for the multithread subject, read Voo's entry.

Comment: Well the most performance gain apart from multi threading comes from only visiting the Live cells, that's already donne. I wouldn't use #5 - introducing a branch and check for every access although that should happen rarely will hurt performance more, especially if you want to use SSE (if the delphi compiler is capable of that?). And using two grids instead of one (a constant memory overhead isn't that bad here) will allow you to get around having to add items to a list and go through that later on (synchronization overhead when multithreading)

Comment: Well, #5 allowed to skip visiting all neighbors, 1 branch to avoid a (nested, depending on implementation) loop, it was a lifesaver.  Now that I implemented #3, I don't know if it's still valid.

Comment: -1: Because you did not answer the question. also: please have a look at golly: http://golly.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Mostly @Ken, the complete sourcecode for the test program:

Note that 99,9% of the time is spend in displaying, because I haven't done anything to
optimize that.

I've created a new SDI-main app and posted the code in that and because I'm lazy I haven't bothered to rename or repaint any controls.

**Project file: sdiapp.dpr**

```
program Sdiapp;

uses
  Forms,
  SDIMAIN in 'SDIMAIN.pas'; {Form1}

{$R *.RES}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**Main form: sdimain.pas**

```
unit SDIMAIN;

interface

uses Windows, Classes, Graphics, Forms, Controls, Menus,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Buttons, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, ImgList, StdActns,
  ActnList, ToolWin;


  {--------------------------------------------
  p and q are bit arrays of 16x16 bits, grouped
  as in 8 int32's as follows

  P00 P04 P08 P0c P10 P14 P18 P1c 
  P01 P05 P09 P0d P11 P15 P19 P1d
  P02 P06 P0a P0e P12 P16 P1a P1e
  P03 P07 P0b P0f P13 P17 P1b P1f
  |
  +----> The bits per int32 are grouped as follows

  The int32's are grouped as follows
  P0 P1
  P2 P3
  P4 P5
  P6 P7

  P and Q are staggered as follows:

  +---------------------------------+ <---- P
  | +-------------------------------|-+ <----Q
  | |                               | |
  | |                               | |
  ...                               ...
  | |                               | |
  +-|-------------------------------+ |
    +---------------------------------+

  Generations start counting from 0,
  all even generations are stored in P.
  all odd generations are stored in Q.
  When generating P->Q, the S, SE and E neighbors are checked.
  When generating Q->P, the N, NW and W neighbors are checked.

  The westernmost P edge in a grid is stored inside that grid.
  Ditto for all easternmost Q edges.

  --------------------------------------------}

const
  cClearQState = $fffffff0;
  cClearPState = $fffff0ff;
  cIndexQ = 1;
  cIndexP = 0;

  ChangeSelf = 0;
  ChangeNW = 1;
  ChangeW = 2;
  ChangeN = 3;

  ChangeSE = 1;
  ChangeE = 2;
  ChangeS = 3;

const
  //A Grid is 128 x 128 pixels.
  GridSizeX = 512 div 8;   //should be 128/8, 1024 for testing.
  GridSizeY = GridSizeX * 2; //32 totaal: 16x32x4bytes =  2048 x 2 (p+q) = 4k per block.
  GridMaxX = GridSizeX - 1;
  GridMaxY = GridSizeY - 1;
  NumberOfCells = GridSizeX * GridSizeY;

  CellSizeX = 8;
  CellSizeY = 4;
  CellMaxX = CellSizeX - 1;
  CellMaxY = CellSizeY - 1;


type
  TUnit = Cardinal;
  TBytes = array[0..3] of byte;

  TChange = array[0..3] of boolean;

type
  TCellBlock = class;
  TFlags = record
    case boolean of
    true: (whole: cardinal);
    false: (part: array[0..3] of byte);
  end;

  //TActiveList = array[0..GridMaxX, 0..GridMaxY] of boolean;
  //TActive = array[0..1] of TActiveList;
  TToDoList = array[-1..NumberOfCells] of cardinal; //Padding on both sides.

  TNewRow = TFlags;

  PCell = ^TCell;
  TCell = record
  public
    p: TUnit;
    q: TUnit;
    procedure SetPixel(x,y: integer; InP: Boolean = true);
    function GeneratePtoQ: cardinal; inline;
    function GenerateQtoP: cardinal; inline;
  end;

  //A grid contains pointers to an other grid, a unit or nil.
  //A grid can contain grids (and nils) or units (and nils), but not both.
  PGrid = ^TGrid;
  TGrid = array[0..GridMaxX,0..GridMaxY] of TCell;


  TCellBlock = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FHasCells: boolean;
    FLevel: integer;
    FGrid: TGrid;
    ToDoP: TToDoList;
    ToDoQ: TToDoList;
    PCount: integer;
    QCount: integer;
    FParent: TCellBlock;
    FMyX,FMyY: integer;
    N,W,NW: TCellBlock;
    S,E,SE: TCellBlock;
    procedure GeneratePtoQ; virtual;
    procedure GenerateQtoP; virtual;
    procedure UpdateFlagsPtoQ; virtual;
    procedure UpdateFlagsQtoP; virtual;
    procedure Generate; virtual;
    procedure Display(ACanvas: TCanvas); virtual;
    procedure SetPixel(x,y: integer);
    property Grid: TGrid read FGrid write FGrid;
  public
    constructor Create(AParent: TCellBlock);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Parent: TCellBlock read FParent;
    property HasCells: boolean read FHasCells;
    property Level: integer read FLevel;
    property MyX: integer read FMyX;
    property MyY: integer read FMyY;
  end;

  TCellParent = class(TCellBlock)
  private
    procedure GeneratePtoQ; override;
    procedure GenerateQtoP; override;
    //procedure Display(Startx,StartY: integer; ACanvas: TCanvas); override;

  public
    constructor CreateFromChild(AChild: TCellBlock; ChildX, ChildY: integer);
    constructor CreateFromParent(AParent: TCellParent);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ToolBar1: TToolBar;
    ToolButton9: TToolButton;
    ToolButton1: TToolButton;
    ToolButton2: TToolButton;
    ToolButton3: TToolButton;
    ToolButton4: TToolButton;
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    FileNew1: TAction;
    FileOpen1: TAction;
    FileSave1: TAction;
    FileSaveAs1: TAction;
    FileExit1: TAction;
    EditCut1: TEditCut;
    EditCopy1: TEditCopy;
    EditPaste1: TEditPaste;
    HelpAbout1: TAction;
    StatusBar: TStatusBar;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    Image1: TImage;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FileNew1Execute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FileSave1Execute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FileExit1Execute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FileOpen1Execute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ToolButton4Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    MyBlock: TCellBlock;
    MyBitmap: TBitmap;
    BitmapData: array[0..1024,0..(1024 div 32)] of integer;
    procedure InitLookupTable;
    procedure RestartScreen;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;



var
  Form1: TForm1;

const
  cLiveCell =      $88888888;
  cLiveVerticalP = $40404040;
  cLiveVerticalQ = $04040404;
  cLiveTop =       $00000088;
  cLiveBottom =    $88000000;
  cLivePCorner =   $00000040;
  cLiveQCorner =   $04000000;

  cUnstableCell =      $22222222;
  cUnstableVerticalP = $10101010;
  cUnstableVerticalQ = $01010101;
  cUnstableTop =       $00000022;
  cUnstableBottom =    $22000000;
  cUnstablePCorner =   $00000010;
  cUnstableQCorner =   $01000000;

  cAllDead = $00000000;
  cAllLive = $ffffffff;

  cLiveRow = $8;
  cLive2x2 = $4;
  cUnstableRow = $2;
  cUnstable8x4 = $22;
  cUnstable2x2 = $1;
  cUnstable2x4 = $11;

  cStateMask: array [0..7] of cardinal =
    ($fffffff0, $ffffff0f, $fffff0ff, $ffff0fff, $fff0ffff, $ff0fffff, $f0ffffff, $0fffffff);

var
  LookupTable: array[0..$FFFF] of byte;
  Generation: int64;

implementation

uses about, sysutils, clipbrd, Math;

{$R *.dfm}

type
  bool = longbool;

procedure getCPUticks(var i : int64);
begin
 asm
   mov ECX,i;
   RDTSC;       //cpu clock in EAX,EDX
   mov [ECX],EAX;
   mov [ECX+4],EDX;
 end;
end;



function IntToBin(AInt: integer): string;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i:= SizeOf(AInt)*8;
  Result:= StringOfChar('0',i);
  while (i > 0) do begin
    if Odd(AInt) then Result[i]:= '1';
    AInt:= AInt shr 1;
    Dec(i);
  end; {while}
end;


constructor TCellBlock.Create(AParent: TCellBlock);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FParent:= AParent;
  ToDoQ[-1]:= $ffffffff;
  ToDoP[-1]:= $ffffffff;
end;

destructor TCellBlock.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;


procedure TCell.SetPixel(x: Integer; y: Integer; InP: Boolean = true);
var
  Mask: cardinal;
  Offset: Integer;
begin
  //0,0 is the topleft pixel, no correction for p,q fase.
  x:= x mod 8;
  y:= y mod 4;
  Offset:= x * 4 + y;
  Mask:= 1 shl Offset;
  if (InP) then p:= p or Mask else q:= q or Mask;
end;

procedure TCellBlock.SetPixel(x: Integer; y: Integer);
var
  GridX, GridY: integer;
  x1,y1: integer;
  i: integer;
begin
  x:= x + (GridSizeX div 2) * CellSizeX;
  y:= y + (GridSizeY div 2) * CellSizeY;
  if Odd(Generation) then begin
    Dec(x); Dec(y);
    QCount:= 0;
  end
  else PCount:= 0;
  GridX:= x div CellSizeX;
  GridY:= y div CellSizeY;
  if (GridX in [0..GridMaxX]) and (GridY in [0..GridMaxY]) then begin
    Grid[GridX,GridY].SetPixel(x,y);
    i:= 0;
    for x1:= 1 to GridMaxX-1 do begin
      for y1:= 1 to GridMaxY-1 do begin
        case Odd(Generation) of
          false: begin
            ToDoP[i]:= (x1 shl 16 or y1);
            Inc(PCount);
          end;
          true: begin
            ToDoQ[i]:= (x1 shl 16 or y1);
            Inc(QCount);
          end;
        end; {case}
        Inc(i);
      end; {for y}
    end; {for x}
  end; {if}
end;

//GeneratePtoQ
//This procedure generates the Q data and QState-flags
//using the P-data and PState-flags.

procedure TCellBlock.Generate;
begin
  if Odd(Generation) then GenerateQtoP
  else GeneratePtoQ;
  Inc(Generation);
end;

const
  MaskS =  $cccccccc;
  MaskE =  $ff000000;
  MaskSE = $cc000000;

procedure TCellBlock.GeneratePtoQ;
var
  x,y: integer;
  i: integer;
  Change: cardinal;
  ToDoA: TToDoList;
  ToDoB: TToDoList;
  A, B: integer;
  done: boolean;
  Address: cardinal;
begin
  i:= 0;
  A:= 0; B:= 0;
  ToDoA[-1]:= $ffffffff;
  ToDoB[-1]:= $ffffffff;
  while (i < PCount) do begin
    y:= ToDoP[i] and $FFFF;
    x:= ToDoP[i] shr 16;
    Inc(i);
    if (x = GridMaxX) or (y = GridMaxY) then continue; //Skip the loop.
    Change:= Grid[x,y].GeneratePtoQ;
    if (Change <> 0) then begin
      Address:= (x shl 16 or y);
      if ToDoA[A-1] <> Address then begin
        ToDoA[A]:= Address; Inc(A);
      end;
      if (Change and MaskS) <> 0 then begin
        ToDoA[A]:= Address + 1;
        Inc(A);
      end; {if S changed}
      if ((Change and MaskE) <> 0) then begin
        Address:= Address + (1 shl 16);
        if ToDoB[B-1] <> Address then begin
          ToDoB[B]:= Address;
          Inc(B);
        end;
        if ((Change and MaskSE) <> 0) then begin
          ToDoB[B]:= Address + 1;
          Inc(B);
        end; {if SE changed}
      end; {if E changed}
    end; {if whole cell changed}
  end; {while}
  ToDoA[A]:= $ffffffff;
  ToDoB[B]:= $ffffffff;
  ToDoB[B+1]:= $ffffffff;


  a:= 0; b:= 0; QCount:= 0;
  Done:= (ToDoA[a] = $ffffffff) and (ToDoB[b] = $ffffffff);
  while not done do begin
    if ToDoA[a] <= ToDoB[b] then begin
      ToDoQ[QCount]:= ToDoA[a]; inc(a); inc(QCount);
      if ToDoA[a] = ToDoB[b] then inc(b);
    end
    else begin
      ToDoQ[QCount]:= ToDoB[b]; inc(b); inc(QCount);
    end;
    Done:= (ToDoA[a] = $ffffffff) and (ToDoB[b] = $ffffffff);
  end; {while}
end;

const
  MaskN =  $33333333;
  MaskW =  $000000ff;
  MaskNW = $00000033;

procedure TCellBlock.GenerateQtoP;
var
  x,y: integer;
  i: integer;
  Change: cardinal;
  ToDoA: TToDoList;
  ToDoB: TToDoList;
  A, B: integer;
  done: boolean;
  Address: cardinal;
begin
  i:= 0;
  A:= 0; B:= 0;
  ToDoA[-1]:= $ffffffff;
  ToDoB[-1]:= $ffffffff;
  while (i < QCount) do begin
    y:= ToDoQ[i] and $FFFF;
    x:= ToDoQ[i] shr 16;
    Inc(i);
    if (x = 0) or (y = 0) then Continue; //Skip the rest of the loop.
    Change:= Grid[x,y].GenerateQtoP;
    if (Change <> 0) then begin
      Address:= (x shl 16 or y);
      if ToDoA[A-1] <> Address then begin
        ToDoA[A]:= Address; Inc(A);
      end;
      if (Change and MaskN) <> 0 then begin
        ToDoA[A]:= Address - 1;
        Inc(A);
      end; {if N changed}
      if ((Change and MaskW) <> 0) then begin
        Address:= Address - (1 shl 16);
        if ToDoB[B-1] <> Address then begin
          ToDoB[B]:= Address;
          Inc(B);
        end;
        if ((Change and MaskNW) <> 0) then begin
          ToDoB[B]:= Address - 1;
          Inc(B);
        end; {if NW changed}
      end; {if W changed}
    end; {if whole cell changed}
  end; {while}
  ToDoA[A]:= $ffffffff;
  ToDoB[B]:= $ffffffff;
  ToDoB[B+1]:= $ffffffff;

  a:= 0; b:= 0; PCount:= 0;
  Done:= (ToDoA[a] = $ffffffff) and (ToDoB[b] = $ffffffff);
  while not done do begin
    if ToDoA[a] <= ToDoB[b] then begin
      ToDoP[PCount]:= ToDoA[a]; inc(a); inc(PCount);
      if ToDoA[a] = ToDoB[b] then inc(b);
    end
    else begin
      ToDoP[PCount]:= ToDoB[b]; inc(b); inc(PCount);
    end;
    Done:= (ToDoA[a] = $ffffffff) and (ToDoB[b] = $ffffffff);
  end; {while}
end;


(*
procedure TCellBlock.GenerateQtoP;
var
  x,y: integer;
  i: integer;
  Change: cardinal;
begin
  i:= 0;
  for x:= 0 to GridMaxX - 1 do begin
    for y:= 0 to GridMaxY -1 do begin
      if Active[cIndexQ][x, y] then begin
        Active[cIndexQ][x, y]:= false;
        ToDo[i]:= x shl 16 or y;
        Inc(i);
      end; {if}
    end; {for y}
  end; {for x}
  while i > 0 do begin
    Dec(i);
    y:= ToDo[i] and $FFFF;
    x:= ToDo[i] shr 16;
    Change:= Grid[x,y].GenerateQtoP;
    Active[cIndexP][x,y]:= Active[cIndexP][x,y] or (Change <> 0);
    Active[cIndexP][x-1,y-1]:= Active[cIndexP][x-1,y-1] or ((Change and $00000033) <> 0);
    Active[cIndexP][x-1,y]:= Active[cIndexP][x-1,y] or     ((Change and $000000ff) <> 0);
    Active[cIndexP][x,y-1]:= Active[cIndexP][x,y-1] or     ((Change and $33333333) <> 0);
  end; {while}
end; (**)

procedure TCellBlock.UpdateFlagsPtoQ;
begin
  //nog in te vullen.
end;

procedure TCellBlock.UpdateFlagsQtoP;
begin
  //nog in te vullen
end;



function TCell.GeneratePtoQ: cardinal;
var
  NewQ: cardinal;
  Change: cardinal;
const
  Mask1 = $f;
  Mask2 = $ff;
  Mask4 = $ffff;

  Row1Mask = $33333333; //0011-0011-0011-0011-0011-0011-0011-0011
  Row2Mask = $cccccccc; //1100-1100-1100-1100-1100-1100-1100-1100

  function MakeNewBrick(p0,p1,p2,p3: cardinal): cardinal; inline;
  var
    Row1, Row2: cardinal;
  begin
    //Generate new Brick using a 2x2 grid of bricks ordered like:
    //p0 p1
    //p2 p3


    //First row inside P0
    if (p0 <> 0) then Row1:=
      LookupTable[p0 and $ffff] or
      LookupTable[(p0 shr 8) and $ffff] shl 8 or
      LookupTable[(p0 shr 16)] shl 16 or
      LookupTable[(p0 shr 24) or (p1 and $ff) shl 8] shl 24
    else Row1:= LookupTable[(p1 and $ff) shl 8] shl 24;
 (**)
    p0:= ((p0 and $cccccccc)) or ((p2 and $33333333));
    p1:= ((p1 and $cc)) or ((p3 and $33));
    if (p0 <> 0) then Row2:=
      LookupTable[p0 and $ffff] or
      LookupTable[(p0 shr 8) and $ffff] shl 8 or
      LookupTable[(p0 shr 16)] shl 16 or
      LookupTable[(p0 shr 24) or ((p1 and $ff) shl 8)] shl 24
    else Row2:= LookupTable[(p1 and $ff) shl 8] shl 24;

    Result:= (Row1 and Row1Mask) or (Row2 and Row2Mask);
  end;

begin
  NewQ:= MakeNewBrick(Self.p, PGrid(@Self)^[1,0].p, PGrid(@Self)^[0,1].p, PGrid(@Self)^[1,1].p);
  Result:= NewQ xor q;
  q:= NewQ;
end;



function TCell.GenerateQtoP: cardinal;
var
  Offset: integer;
  NewP: cardinal;
  Change: cardinal;

const
  Row1Mask = $33333333; //0011-0011-0011-0011-0011-0011-0011-0011
  Row2Mask = $cccccccc; //1100-1100-1100-1100-1100-1100-1100-1100

  function MakeNewBrick(q0,q1,q2,q3: cardinal): cardinal; inline;
  var
    Row1, Row2: cardinal;
  begin
    //Generate new Brick using a 2x2 grid of bricks ordered like:
    //q3 q2
    //q1 q0

    if (q0 <> 0) then Row1:=
      LookupTable[(q0 shr 16)] shl 26 or
      LookupTable[(q0 shr 8 ) and $ffff] shl 18 or
      LookupTable[(q0       ) and $ffff] shl 10 or
      LookupTable[((q0 and $ff) shl 8) or (q1 shr 24)] shl 2
    else Row1:= LookupTable[(q1 shr 24)] shl 2;

(*
    q0:= ((q0 and $33333333) shl 2) or ((q2 and $cccccccc) shr 2);
    q1:= ((q1 and $33000000) shl 2) or ((q3 and $cc000000) shr 2);
    if (q0 <> 0) then Row2:=
      LookupTable[(q0 shr 16) and $ffff] shl 24 or
      LookupTable[(q0 shr 8) and $ffff] shl 16 or
      LookupTable[(q0      ) and $ffff] shl 8 or
      LookupTable[((q0 and $ff) shl 8) or (q1 shr 24)]
    else Row2:= LookupTable[(q1 shr 24)];
(**)

    q0:= ((q0 and $33333333)) or ((q2 and $cccccccc));
    q1:= ((q1 and $33000000)) or ((q3 and $cc000000));
    if (q0 <> 0) then Row2:=
      LookupTable[(q0 shr 16)] shl 22 or
      LookupTable[(q0 shr 8) and $ffff] shl 14 or
      LookupTable[(q0      ) and $ffff] shl 6 or
      LookupTable[((q0 and $ff) shl 8) or (q1 shr 24)] shr 2
    else Row2:= LookupTable[(q1 shr 24)] shr 2;

    Result:= (Row1 and Row2Mask) or (Row2 and Row1Mask);
  end;



begin
  Offset:= -1;
  NewP:= MakeNewBrick(Self.q, PGrid(@Self)^[Offset,0].q, PGrid(@Self)^[0,Offset].q, PGrid(@Self)^[Offset, Offset].q);
  Result:= NewP xor P;
  P:= NewP;
end;

procedure TCellBlock.Display(ACanvas: TCanvas);
var
  GridX,GridY: integer;
  //Offset: integer;

  procedure DisplayCell(ACell: TCell);
  var
    x,y,x1,y1: integer;
    Row, Mask: integer;
    DoPixel: boolean;
    Offset: integer;
    DrawOffset: integer;
    InP: boolean;
  begin
    DrawOffset:= (Generation and 1);
    InP:= not(Odd(Generation));

    for y:= 0 to CellMaxY do begin
      for x:= 0 to CellMaxX do begin
        //if (x = 0) or (y = 0) then ACanvas.Pixels[GridX*16+x+Offset,GridY*16+y+Offset]:= clBtnFace;
        //0,0 is the topleft pixel, no correction for p,q fase.
        x1:= x mod 8;
        y1:= y mod 4;
        Offset:= x1 * 4 + y1;
        Mask:= 1 shl Offset;
        if (InP) then DoPixel:= (ACell.p and Mask) <> 0
        else DoPixel:= (ACell.q and Mask) <> 0;

        if DoPixel then ACanvas.Pixels[GridX*CellSizeX+x+DrawOffset, GridY*CellSizeY+y+DrawOffset]:= clBlack;
      end; {for x}
    end; {for y}
  end;  (**)


begin
  ACanvas.Rectangle(-1,-1,1000,1000);
  FillChar(Form1.BitmapData, SizeOf(Form1.BitmapData), #0);
  for GridY:= 0 to GridMaxY do begin
    for GridX:= 0 to GridMaxX do begin
      if Int64(Grid[GridX, GridY]) <> 0 then begin
        DisplayCell(Grid[GridX,GridY]);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

//--------------------------------------
//A Parent is every layer above the ground level
//the tree grows from the bottom up.
//A new parent is placed on top of the last one and
//always has one and only one child to start with, from there
//the tree grows down again.

constructor TCellParent.CreateFromChild(AChild: TCellBlock; ChildX: Integer; ChildY: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create(nil);
end;

constructor TCellParent.CreateFromParent(AParent: TCellParent);
begin
  inherited Create(AParent);
end;

destructor TCellParent.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TCellParent.GeneratePtoQ;
begin
end;

procedure TCellParent.GenerateQtoP;
begin
end;

//The bitmap for the lookup table is as follows:
// 0  2  4  6
//   +----+
// 1 |3  5| 7
// 8 |A  C| E
//   +----+
// 9  B  D  F
// The inner 2x2 cells are looked up.
// so 0241358AC make up bit 3 etc.

procedure TForm1.InitLookupTable;
const
  //Masks for normal order.
  MaskNW = $0757;   //0000-0111-0101-0111
  MaskSW = $0EAE;   //0000-1110-1010-1110
  MaskNE = $7570;   //0111-0101-0111-0000
  MaskSE = $EAE0;   //1110-1010-1110-0000

  //Bitlocations for normal order
  BitNW = $0020; //0000-0000-0010-0000
  BitSW = $0040; //0000-0000-0100-0000
  BitNE = $0200; //0000-0020-0000-0000
  BitSE = $0400; //0000-0100-0000-0000


  //Lookup table also has a shifted order. here the bottom half of the N word
  //and the top half of the south word combine.
  //Like so:
  // 2 6 A E
  // 3 7 B F
  // 0 4 8 C
  // 1 5 9 D

  //Mask for split order.
  Mask2NW = $0D5D;     // 0000-1101-0101-1101
  Mask2SW = $0BAB;     // 0000-1011-1010-1011
  Mask2NE = $D5D0;     // 1101-0101-1101-0000
  Mask2SE = $BAB0;     // 1011-1010-1011-0000

  //Bitlocations for split order
  Bit2NW = $0080; // 0000-0000-1000-0000
  Bit2SW = $0010; // 0000-0000-0001-0000
  Bit2NE = $0800; // 0000-1000-0000-0000
  Bit2SE = $0100; // 0000-0001-0000-0000

  ResultNW = $01;
  ResultSW = $02;
  ResultNE = $10;
  ResultSE = $20;

  Result2NW = $04;
  Result2SW = $08;
  Result2NE = $40;
  Result2SE = $80;

var
  i: integer;
  iNW, iNE, iSW, iSE: cardinal;
  Count: integer;
  ResultByte: byte;

  function GetCount(a: integer): integer;
  var
    c: integer;
  begin
    Result:= 0;
    for c:= 0 to 15 do begin
      if Odd(a shr c) then Inc(Result);
    end; {for c}
  end; {GetCount}

begin
  //Fill the normal lookup.
  for i:= 0 to $ffff do begin
    ResultByte:= 0;
    iNW:= i and MaskNW;
    Count:= GetCount(iNW);
    case Count of   //count excluding bit itself
      3: ResultByte:= ResultNW;
      2: if ((i and BitNW) <> 0) then ResultByte:= ResultNW;
    end;
    iSW:= i and MaskSW;
    Count:= GetCount(iSW);
    case Count of
      3: ResultByte:= ResultByte or ResultSW;
      2: if ((i and BitSW) <> 0) then ResultByte:= ResultByte or ResultSW;
    end;
    iNE:= i and MaskNE;
    Count:= GetCount(iNE);
    case Count of
      3: ResultByte:= ResultByte or ResultNE;
      2: if ((i and BitNE) <> 0) then ResultByte:= ResultByte or ResultNE;
    end;
    iSE:= i and MaskSE;
    Count:= GetCount(iSE);
    case Count of
      3: ResultByte:= ResultByte or ResultSE;
      2: if ((i and BitSE) <> 0) then ResultByte:= ResultByte or ResultSE;
    end;
    LookupTable[i]:= ResultByte;
  end; {for i}


  //Fill the shifted lookup.
  for i:= 0 to $ffff do begin
    ResultByte:= 0;
    iNW:= i and Mask2NW;
    Count:= GetCount(iNW);
    case Count of   //count excluding bit itself
      3: ResultByte:= Result2NW;
      2: if ((i and Bit2NW) <> 0) then ResultByte:= Result2NW;
    end;
    iSW:= i and Mask2SW;
    Count:= GetCount(iSW);
    case Count of
      3: ResultByte:= ResultByte or Result2SW;
      2: if ((i and Bit2SW) <> 0) then ResultByte:= ResultByte or Result2SW;
    end;
    iNE:= i and Mask2NE;
    Count:= GetCount(iNE);
    case Count of
      3: ResultByte:= ResultByte or Result2NE;
      2: if ((i and Bit2NE) <> 0) then ResultByte:= ResultByte or Result2NE;
    end;
    iSE:= i and Mask2SE;
    Count:= GetCount(iSE);
    case Count of
      3: ResultByte:= ResultByte or Result2SE;
      2: if ((i and Bit2SE) <> 0) then ResultByte:= ResultByte or Result2SE;
    end;
    LookupTable[i]:= LookupTable[i] or ResultByte;
  end; {for i}  (**)
end;

procedure TForm1.RestartScreen;
begin
  MyBlock.Free;
  MyBlock:= TCellBlock.Create(nil);
  //MyBlock.SetPixel(5,7);
  //MyBlock.SetPixel(6,7);
  //MyBlock.SetPixel(7,7);
  //MyBlock.SetPixel(7,6);
  //MyBlock.SetPixel(6,5);

  MyBlock.SetPixel(10,0);
  MyBlock.SetPixel(11,0);
  MyBlock.SetPixel(9,1);
  MyBlock.SetPixel(10,1);
  MyBlock.SetPixel(10,2);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(MyBlock) then begin
    MyBlock.Generate;
    MyBlock.Display(Image1.Canvas);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ToolButton4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(MyBlock) then begin
    MyBlock.Generate;
    MyBlock.Display(Image1.Canvas);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FileNew1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InitLookupTable;
  FillChar(BitmapData, SizeOf(BitmapData), #0);
  MyBitmap:= TBitmap.Create;
  MyBitmap.SetSize(1024,1024);
  MyBitmap.PixelFormat:= pf1bit;
  MyBitmap.Monochrome:= true;
  //MyBitmap.Handle:= CreateBitmap(1000,1000,1,2,nil);

  Generation:= 0;

  RestartScreen;
  MyBlock.Display(Image1.Canvas);
  //if (Sender = FileNew1) then Timer1.Enabled:= not(Timer1.Enabled);

end;

procedure TForm1.FileOpen1Execute(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,a: integer;
  start, eind: int64;
  Diff: double;
  LowDiff: double;
begin
  LowDiff:= MaxInt;
  for a:= 0 to 10 do begin
    FileNew1Execute(Sender);
    GetCPUTicks(start);
    for i:= 0 to 1000 do begin
      MyBlock.Generate;
    end;
    GetCPUTicks(eind);
    //Label1.Caption:= IntToStr(Eind - Start);
    Diff:= Eind - start;
    LowDiff:= Min(Diff, LowDiff);

    Label1.Caption:= Format('%10.0n',[lowdiff]) + ' CPU cycles per 1,000 generations';
    Clipboard.AsText:= Label1.Caption;
  end; {for a}
  MyBlock.Display(Image1.Canvas);
end;


procedure TForm1.FileSave1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled:= not(Timer1.Enabled);
end;

procedure TForm1.FileExit1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;


initialization
  Generation:= 0;

end.
```

Stackoverflow does not allow me to post the form file due to a size limit, but I hope you can manage without.